# Grammatical role of можно

Tags: грамматика, этимология

I have learned how to translate "можно" in phrases (e.g. with "it is possible", "one can", "it can be (done)").

However, I would like to know the actual grammatical role of the word.

My conjecture is the following:

It is an adjective singular neutrum that simply means "possible", but which is no longer used outside this kind of phrase, but still exists in composite adjectives like возмо́жный.

I would like to know if this is right and if it indeed comes from an older adjective no longer in common use.

Answer (score 2):

It's predicative. equal to `возможно`

It's really hard to explain fully but will try to clarify some things

you can say `мне можно` -> `I may`

but

you can't say `мне возможно` but `это для меня возможно` - `it is possible for me`

In questions `можно` means `may` like a `question to action`...

`можно мне ....` -> `May I ....`

And `возможно-ли что ...` will strongly still be `is it possible that ...`

in nutshell `можно` and `возможно` have got the same base `мож` and same suffix but used in different ways...

`как можно скорее - as soon as possible`

`возможно земля круглая - maybe the earth is round`